# pandas efficient groupby apply two dataframe together with tqdm

Tags: python, pandas, progress-bar, pandas-groupby, tqdm

### Method 1 (clear but very slow)

```
product_ids = df1.product_id.unique()
store_ids= df1.store_id.unique()

with tqdm(total=product_ids.shape[0]*store_ids.shape[0]) as t:
    for product_id in product_ids:
        p1 = df1.loc[(df1.product_id==product_id)]
        p2 = df2.loc[(df2.product_id==product_id)]
        for store_id in store_ids:
            df11 = p1.loc[(p1.store_id==store_id)]
            df22 = p2.loc[(p2.store_id==store_id)]
            train_predict(df11, df22)
            t.update()
```

### Method 2 (fast but I don't like )

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = df2.reset_index().set_index(['store_id', 'product_id'])

def _reduce(df_orderitems):
    MIN_ORDERITEMS_COUNT = 30

    store_id = df_orderitems.store_id.iloc[0]
    product_id = df_orderitems.product_id.iloc[0]

    try:
        ## !!!! here refer to global df2, I don't like  !!!!!
        df_stockquantitylog = df2.loc[(store_id, product_id)]
        ## !!!! here refer to global df2, I don't like  !!!!!   
    except KeyError:
        logger.info('## df_orderitems shape:%s , cannot find (%s, %s)' % (df_orderitems.shape, store_id, product_id) )
        return

    train_predict(df_orderitems, df_stockquantitylog)

tqdm.pandas()
df1.groupby(['store_id', 'product_id']).progress_apply(_reduce)
```

I need tqdm to show progress bar, but Method1 is very slow(I think because of inefficient print). Method 2 which have `tqdm`'s `pandas` patch, another key point I think is `groupby.apply` . But I can't figure out how to make method 1 as fast as method 2.

Note:

`df1.shape[0] != df2.shape[0]` , can't merge. 
They are dumped from database . For example,  there may be  10 rows with same `store_id A`   and `product_id B` in `df1` , and 100 rows with same `store_id A`   and `product_id B` in `df2` . They can't be merged before proper processing:

Need:

1. select by store_id and product_id first (in each df1 and df2)
2. You can't do join without selections.  I have to apply **different aggregation** with `df1[(df1.store_id==A)&(df1.product_id==B)])` and `df2[(df2.store_id==A)&(df2.product_id==B)])`, to give they same DatatimeIndex for merging , because some meta data columns need aggregate by date. You can't do this without selections, because different combinations of `store_id` and `product_id` have duplicated dates.
3. Then the two result are mergable(joinable)
4. train model

Answer (score 0):

So if your only concern with Method 2 is that you don't want to look at the global df2, why not pass it in as a second parameter to your function? 
Eg.

```
def _reduce(df_orderitems, df_): ...
```

But I wouldn't suggest doing precisely either of the methods you've outlined here.

Iterating through a dataframe like you do in Method 1 is never going to be as fast as using `apply`, because `apply` is internally optimized using Cython. In fact, it's going to be extremely slow (as you've found). [Here](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) is a good explanation as to why and your options for making operations faster.

Your question is a bit vague as to why else you don't like method 2, but I'd do two things, if I were in your shoes.

1. I'd use the SQL-like operations in pandas to join the two dataframes together.

You have overlapping columns ('store_id' and 'product_id') that appear in both df1 and df2, so I'd do an SQL-style `join` in pandas to combine the two dataframes. That way you don't have to deal with the indexing bits you're currently doing.

Let's first create some dummy data that I think represents your situation:

```
  df1 = pd.DataFrame({"store_id": ['A','A','A','B','B'],
                      "product_id": [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
                      "record_number": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
                      "data": [21, 22, 28, 26, 25]})

  df2 = pd.DataFrame({"store_id":['A','A','A','B','B', 'B'],
                      "product_id": [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], 
                      "more_data":[35, 39, 36, 33, 37, 32]})
```

Then you can use the `join` function to merge the two dataframes, SQL-style, on the overlapping columns (`join` uses the indices of the dataframe). This maps the data from df2 onto the data in df1 to create a new, merged dataframe. ([Described in detail in the pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html))

```
 merged = df1.join(df2.set_index(['store_id','product_id']), 
                   how='left', 
                   on=['store_id','product_id'], 
                   rsuffix='_df2_data')
```

Which gives you

```
    store_id  product_id  record_number  product_data  more_product_data
  0        A           0              0            21                 35
  1        A           1              1            22                 39
  2        A           2              2            28                 36
  3        B           1              3            26                 37
  4        B           0              4            25                 33
```

Depending on your data completeness, you probably want to check for NaNs

You can also filter, transform, etc your data as your need (if there are other steps to your processing step)

2. Then I'd use `apply` (`progress_apply`) to do the prediction step

You can either create a new function, or use a lambda function, depending on your situation

```
def train_predict(a, b): 
    return a + b 

def predict_outcome(df_row):     
    return train_predict(df_row[['product_data']].values[0], 
                         df_row[['more_product_data']].values[0])

tqdm.pandas(desc='predict the outcome')
merged['prediction'] = merged.progress_apply(lambda x:  train_predict(x['product_data'],x['more_product_data']),
                                             axis='columns')

# or 

tqdm.pandas(desc='predict the outcome')
merged['prediction'] = merged.progress_apply(predict_outcome, axis='columns')
```

(the `axis='columns'` argument tells `apply` to iterate through the df's rows)

Comment: You can't do join.  I have to apply **different aggregation** with `df1[(df1.store_id==A)&(df1.product_id==B)])` and `df2[(df2.store_id==A)&(df2.product_id==B)])`, to give they same index for merging . Some meta data columns need aggregate by date. You can't do this without selections, because different combinations of `store_id` and `product_id` have duplicated dates.

Comment: I don't really understand what it is you're asking for; it sounds like you might want to do separate aggregation steps on each of your dataframes first, then do the join (if you're trying to, say, sum some 'inventory' or some such column for all product_id, store_id combinations, you can do that first to get unique observations). But as I say, I can't visualize what you're asking for. Can you be any more specific about the data? (eg., add dummy data, an example agg step, and an example of what the final data should look like?)